# Can I resize the K-menu in Kubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, kubuntu, kde

I have a question about the K-menu in Kubuntu. How can I resize it vertically so it makes better use of my screen estate? Alternatively, can I set it to use

1. two columns, or
2. smaller symbols

such that I can squeeze more favorites into the existing size of the K-menu? My usual screen resolution is 1920x1080.

**System version is:**

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS
Release:        12.04
Codename:       precise
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Kickoff**

http://userbase.kde.org/Plasma/Kickoff

> Kickoff Application Launcher
>
> Kickoff is the default application launcher of the Plasma
>   desktop...You can also resize Kickoff: grab the top right corner of
>   Kickoff with the mouse pointer (it turns to a pair of arrows directed
>   diagonally) and drag Kickoff to the desired size.

There is a wish/bug (Bug 163283 - icon size in kickoff should be configurable): https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=163283

Other KDE launchers: http://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?59851-KDE-Application-Launchers

Comment: You can only resize the widget if it's on the Plasma desktop, it won't provide a way to resize when it's opened from the panel.

Comment: @gertvdijk: you seem to be right, it was of course my instinct to try that before posting the question, but the mouse pointer did not change to a handle.

Comment: The Kickoff widget can be resized when it is opened from the panel - 'grab the corner of Kickoff with the mouse pointer'.

Comment: @user26687 You're right. I'd swear this wasn't working on the machine I was working on earlier, but I have to confirm this does work.

Comment: @user26687: the problem was that it only works in the corner, not just anywhere on the edges.